# Join tables by ids in JSON array in PGSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (refer to it as **A**) with 1 column (refer to it as **c**) that contains a stringified JSON array in the follow format:

```
[
  {"sys": {"type": "Link", "linkType": "Entry", "id": "27OfJChoPO894W4rA6bQ67"}},
  {"sys": {"type": "Link", "linkType": "Entry", "id": "2ygvvrBSPuWw0uTW4jdDP2"}}
]
```

Please, note that the array have variable length. The *id* fields refer to the ID of the second table (**B**). So, I need to select all fields from **A**, but populate **c** with a column from **B**.

I tried looking for JSON functions to help me get the *ids*, but I couldn't progress from an array of *ids* to finally populating it with the column from **B**. So, my current idea is creating a new table to hold the relation between **A** and **B**. What's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a7d1b47133779a6fb6230ce5724eb190)

You can expand your array and use the elements in the `JOIN` condition

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    a,
    json_array_elements(c) as elems
JOIN b ON b.id = elems -> 'sys' ->> 'id'
```

However, please think about normalizing your data. You shouldn't store JSON data directly if you don't need it, especially arrays are difficult to handle. If you can save the data in to appropriate tables/columns, every single action (update, search, filter and of course join) would be easier and much faster. Furthermore you have the chance for proper indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This is a work in progress to export data from a content document-based DB to SQL DB and then sync plug to Google BigQuery. So, this SQL DB won't need any update, complex searches or filtering, as I only need to be able to get specific fields based on the ids on BigQuery.

Comment: I got to reach getting the values, but ideally I still need to merge the values back to have a single *id* on the table, instead of one row for each value on **c** column.

Comment: Got through final step by doing `string_agg` and `group by` *id*.